# Can't enable clicked disabled button in android

Tags: android, button, isenabled, disable

I'm struggeling to enable a disabled `button` when it's clicked. I know it sounds weird, but let me explain: when `index` equals -1 the `button` should be disabled. If `index` is greater than -1 the `button` should be enabled. The problem is when I click on the disabled `button` and `index` is greater than -1, the `button` is still disabled. I tried `btn.setOnclicklister(null)`, but it didn't work.

the code:

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    if (index == -1){
                        btn.setOnClickListener(null);
                        btn.setEnabled(false);
                        btn.setClickable(false);


                    }else if (index > -1){

                       btn.setOnClickListener(this);
                        btn.setEnabled(true);
                        btn.setClickable(true);

                    }


                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for the question. Your notes on setOnClicklistener made me realize that i was using an incorrect condition which cached value was not being properly updated and thus blocking the button to be enabled after being disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enable `OnClickListener` every time you set `index` to not -1:

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
     // do something helpful you want on click
     // and disable the button
      if (index == -1){
         btn.setOnClickListener(null);
         btn.setEnabled(false);
         btn.setClickable(false);
     }
  }
}
```

And somewhere:

```
...
index = 1;
btn.setOnClickListener(listener);
btn.setEnabled(true);
btn.setClickable(true);
...
```